# Compare Validation for drop down list with time in AM/PM format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 4 drop downs: here is the drop down code.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_TimeFromMon" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="6" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="7" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="8" Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="9" Value="9"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="10" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="11" Value="11"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="12" Value="12"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_MonFromAMPM" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="AM" Value="AM"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="PM" Value="PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>

                                &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="Gray" Text="to"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_TimeToMon" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="6" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="7" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="8" Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="9" Value="9"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="10" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="11" Value="11"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="12" Value="12"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_MonToAMPM" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="AM" Value="AM"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="PM" Value="PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

one drop down is for from time in 12 hours the other is AM/PM. same repeats for to drop down. How can a compare validator work, so that we can verify that to time is greater then from time. AM/PM. I tried Compare validator on both, but it is giving error when i select drop with whatever values. please point me to right direction. If this is not possible with compare validator, then sample code for jquery or javascrpt for validation. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try converting to 24 hour hour time based on a small javasript function taking the input and applying the calculated 24 hour format into a hidden field. Then using that hidden field to validate from?

Comment: omg... stop do it, use other control like `timePicker`

Comment: Also what @burning_LEGION said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a customvalidator like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server"
ErrorMessage="Select a valid time" OnServerValidate="TimeValidate">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void TimeValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
        int fromVal = int.Parse(DDL_TimeFromMon.SelectedValue)
        int toVal = int.Parse(DDL_TimeToMon.SelectedValue)
        string fromAMPM = ddl_MonFromAMPM.SelectedValue
        string toAMPM = ddl_MonToAMPM.SelectedValue

        if(fromAMPM == "AM" && toAMPM == "PM")
            args.IsValid = True
        else if(toAMPM == "AM" && fromAMPM == "PM")
            args.IsValid = False
        else
            args.IsValid = fromVal < toVal 
}
```